# Is there a way to fix line alignation in pdfminer?

Tags: python, pdfminer

I'm trying to convert a pdf file to text, using "pdfminer.six" on python 3.7.3. I want to get lines such as

```
date-place of birth:    03.01.1976 antalya

marital status:         single

military service:       completed
```

as accurate as I can.

I tried to change the variables in LAParams() which belongs to the pdfminer.layouts. The example code can be seen below

```py
def get_text_from_pdf(path):
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    retstr = io.StringIO()
    codec = 'utf-8'
    # default_laparams = LAParams(line_overlap=0.5, char_margin=2.0, line_margin=0.5, # word_margin=0.1, boxes_flow=0.5,
    #                      detect_vertical=False, all_texts=False)
     laparams = LAParams(line_overlap=.6, char_margin=1.5, line_margin=1.1, word_margin=0.3, boxes_flow=.6,
                         detect_vertical=False, all_texts=False)
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)
    fp = open(path, 'rb')
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    password = ""
    maxpages = 0
    caching = True
    pagenos = set()
    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp, pagenos, maxpages=maxpages, password=password, caching=caching,
                                  check_extractable=True):
        interpreter.process_page(page)
    fp.close()
    device.close()
    string = retstr.getvalue()
    # string = re.sub(u'\x00', 'i', string)
    retstr.close()
    return string.lower()
```

I end up with a result which can be seen below.

```
date-place of birth:

marital status:

military service:

health:

03.01.1976  antalya
single
completed
```

I want to end up with a result such as:

```
date-place of birth:    03.01.1976 antalya

marital status:         single

military service:       completed
```

If there is anyone who worked on a similar problem or knows the solution, I'd appreciate. I am trying to change the parameters on parallel and will update the question if I find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your characters are spaced wide apart. You can try altering LAParams in the code, `LAParams()` has word_margin set by default which is 1.0, since your document has spaced out words, which are recognized as bigger words, that is the possible cause of the problems.

Try replacing `LAParams()` with `LAParams(char_margin = 20)`.

Reply to this thread to know if this helps.